# Call servelt from jsp inside <a> tag

Tags: jsp, servlets

How can I call a servlet from jsp inside an `<a>` tag and pass him a parameter ?

```
<a href="???" />
```

I can write `<a href="/servletName" />` but how to pass him a parameter ?

Comment: <a href="/servletName?param=value" />

Answer (score -2, accepted):

yes You can do that in two ways:

1. create a function with an ajax call to your servlet.
2. point your **href** to the servlet link (as JB Nizat mentioned)

for the first method, you can follow the below way (if you use jquery) :

```
function callServer(){
   $.ajax({
            url: 'ServletName',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'parameter1='+parameter1,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //console.log("SERVLET DATA: " + data);
                if (typeof (data) !== 'undefined' && data !== '' && data !== null) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(response);

               }

           },error: function(data){

           };
});       

}
```

and call this function in your  tag like below:

```
<a href="javascript:callServer();"> </a>
```

or the much better way like :

```
<a href="#" onclick="callServer();"> </a>
```

you can select the better approach !

Answer (score -1):

Using Anchor tag without Ajax like this you can try

```
<a href="servletName?paramName1=value1&paramName2=value2">click me to send parameter to servlet</a>
```